# Shader Change during runtime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader, gameobject

I am trying to change shader on a trigger event during run time. However, when I used Debug.Log to check if all is right or wrong and everything runs except the shader does not change. There is something I missed ? Any help could be appreciated. Thanks very much

```
public void shaderChange() 
{
    rend = gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>();
    shader1 = Shader.Find("Standard");
    shader2 = Shader.Find("Shader2");

    isActiveClip = !isActiveClip;
    if(isActiveClip == true)
    {
        rend.material.shader = shader2;
    }
    else
    {
        rend.material.shader = shader1;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to manipulate shaders is to change the assigned materials on the object.
This means instancing a material for each use case and switching materials at runtime.
This is because the material itself is dependent on the shader when being created.